# Apple Watch and Core Data iCloud Syncing

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

I've been wrestling with this problem for a while now and can't seem to find anything on the topic. There are plenty of example on how to use Core Data with Apple Watch, but none that have iCloud support, so I'm hoping someone can shed some light on this subject.

I have an app that uses Core Data and the NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey option when creating the persistent store to make it sync to iCloud and between devices. This works great between iPhone and iPad. However, Apple Watch syncing is spotty at best. Sometimes it works, sometimes not and when it does an initial sync it doesn't seem to sync anything after that.

The reason as I see it is, even though the Watch app is an extension of the iPhone app, because it uses NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey it created a database under another folder instead of using the same one as the iPhone.

Path for the database for the iPhone

```
iPhone:
PFUbiquitySetupContainerIdentifierKey: 8B652C84-62E1-4FFF-B822-13C90C19DC5F
file:///Users/Aaron/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/
6E2EE13A-3148-4693-A92F-7B23C709CF78/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/
B7DEE2C6-D345-460C-884D-74C011BF98BA/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/
nobody~simA7716E1E-6B21-5DAA-AF81-CAF6AE77A985/iCloudDATA/
8B652C84-62E1-4FFF-B822-13C90C19DC5F/store/appname)
```

Path for the database for the Apple Watch

```
Watch:
PFUbiquitySetupContainerIdentifierKey: 44220421-4F7C-46AC-B3D7-6ABEDA62C77B
file:///Users/Aaron/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/
6E2EE13A-3148-4693-A92F-7B23C709CF78/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/
B7DEE2C6-D345-460C-884D-74C011BF98BA/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/
nobody~simA7716E1E-6B21-5DAA-AF81-CAF6AE77A985/iCloudDATA/
44220421-4F7C-46AC-B3D7-6ABEDA62C77B/store/appname)
```

Notice that the tile paths are exactly the same with exception to the PFUbiquitySetupContainerIdentifierKey that is in the paths, each device has their own.

If I remove the store option PFUbiquitySetupContainerIdentifierKey, it works fine, but then the devices won't sync with each other.

I was wondering if anyone else has had this problem or any possible solution to it, or am I just doing it all wrong?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: After contacting Apple dev support, it seems this is a known issue with Core Data & iCloud syncing when the code for that is in an extension. I had to move all my data handling back to the main bundle for it to work again.

Link to known issue thread: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1051015#1051015